texlive-pdflatex tikz/pgf library error
I am trying to compile a somewhat simple document with the openSUSE texlive distribution of pdflatex and I am getting the following error:
! Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'tikzmark'. I looked for 
files named tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex and pgflibrarytikzmark.code.tex, but n
either could be found in the current texmf trees..

I thought this would be an easy fix because I was able to locate the first file and just moved it to where the rest of the libraries used were, but this did not change anything.  I came here because I could only find one mention of the second file anywhere and the solution used in the link does not apply to me.

The second file (pgflibrary...) doesn't exist, that's just TeX telling you that it looked for it as a fallback because it didn't find the first file. Tikzmark has been in texlive for a very long time, so either the texlive fro  openSUSE is extremely old, or you didn't install enough of it. I don't know about openSUSE but I do know that other Linux distros split texlive into several packages. Have a look to see if tikzmark is in some part you haven't yet installed.

Oh, and if you move files in tex's file structure then sometimes you have to tell it what you've done. That usually involves running mktexlsr (which I might have misremembered) to rebuild the filename cache.

Thanks for clarifying, this worked.  I am new to self-hosting latex and this would have taken me a long time to figure out.

Note (for all applications not just tex) it's not good practice to move files "by hand" into directories managed by your linux package manager I don't know what opensuse uses but linux distributions typically uses yum or apt or rpm or ... and if your tex was installed using such a system you should install tikzmark in the same way so that it can manage package dependencies correctly
